# 301 Redirect and query strings

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect, querystring

I am looking to create a 301 redirect based purely on a query string see b

```
OLD URL: olddomain.com/?pc=/product/9999
New URL: newurl.php?var=yup
```

My normal way of doing this would be

```
redirect 301 pc=/product/9999 newurl.php?var=yup
```

But this time I am trying to match a URL that that only contains the domain and a query string...

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to solve my problems:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pc=/product/9999
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/index.php?var=yup [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^\?pc=/product/9999$ http://newdomain/newurl.php?var=yup [NC,R=301,L]`

RegEx could be a little off. I did that off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks, but as it happend i just solved it myself.. Check my answer